# Рисование на окне другого приложения с помощью WinAPI

Tags: c#, winapi, графика, gdi

Нужно написать на С# программу, которая будет определять над каким окном Windows сейчас находится курсор и обводить это окно рамкой (указывая пользователю, над каким элементом находится курсор, ведь в WinApi, окном является не только само окно, содержащее в себе множество других элементов, но и эти элементы тоже являются окнами).

Handler окна под курсором получить легко:

```
...
Point point;
WinApi.GetCursorPos(out point);
WinApi.WindowFromPoint(point);
...
```

Но вот нарисовать что то на окне не выходит, хоть убейте.

```
public static void drawSelectionRectangle(IntPtr handler)
{
    Rectangle rectangle;
    WinApi.GetWindowRect(handler, out rectangle);

    WinApi.PAINTSTRUCT paintProperties;
    IntPtr paintContext = WinApi.BeginPaint(handler, out paintProperties);

    IntPtr pen = WinApi.CreatePen(WinApi.PenStyle.PS_SOLID, 5, (uint) ColorTranslator.ToWin32(Color.Red));
    WinApi.SelectObject(paintContext, pen);

    WinApi.Rectangle(paintContext, rectangle.Left, rectangle.Top, rectangle.Right, rectangle.Bottom);

    WinApi.ValidateRect(handler, IntPtr.Zero);
    WinApi.EndPaint(handler, ref paintProperties);
}
```

`drawSelectionRectangle(IntPtr handler)` вызывал и одиночно (по нажатию кнопки) и в цикле (так как предполагал, что отрисовка может выполнятся за один кадр, после чего, исчезать). Ни так ни так не работает.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем проблема... Скоро курсовой сдавать, а ничего не готово :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Проблема в неверном подходе. Во-первых, забудьте про функцию *BeginPaint* (вне обработки сообщения *WM_PAINT*), во-вторых, рисовать надо не в контексте целевого окна, а в контексте его родительского окна (контекст окна позволяет рисовать только в его клиентской области, а рамка-то нам нужна снаружи).

Я предлагаю сделать как-то так:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace DrawingTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        static extern bool GetCursorPos(out POINT lpPoint);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr WindowFromPoint(POINT p);                

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hwnd, out RECT lpRect);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern bool ScreenToClient(IntPtr hWnd, ref POINT lpPoint);        

        [DllImport("user32.dll", ExactSpelling = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public static extern IntPtr GetParent(IntPtr hWnd);

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //получаем окно в текущей позиции курсора  
            POINT pt;
            GetCursorPos(out pt);
            IntPtr hwnd = WindowFromPoint(pt);

            //получаем родительское окно
            IntPtr hwnd_p = GetParent(hwnd);

            //получаем границы окна   
            RECT rc;
            GetWindowRect(hwnd, out rc);

            //перевод из экранных координат в клиентские
            POINT pt1=new POINT(rc.Left,rc.Top), pt2=new POINT(rc.Right,rc.Bottom);
            ScreenToClient(hwnd_p, ref pt1);
            ScreenToClient(hwnd_p, ref pt2);
            RECT rc_client = new RECT();
            rc_client.Left = pt1.X-1; rc_client.Top = pt1.Y-1;
            rc_client.Right = pt2.X; rc_client.Bottom = pt2.Y;

            //формируем структуру для GDI+
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(rc_client.Left, rc_client.Top, rc_client.Right - rc_client.Left, rc_client.Bottom - rc_client.Top);

            //получаем контекст окна            
            Graphics g = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromHwnd(hwnd_p);
            using (g)
            {
                //рисуем прямоугольник
                g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, rect);
            }

        }
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct POINT
    {
        public int X;
        public int Y;

        public POINT(int x, int y)
        {
            this.X = x;
            this.Y = y;
        }

        public POINT(System.Drawing.Point pt) : this(pt.X, pt.Y) { }

        public static implicit operator System.Drawing.Point(POINT p)
        {
            return new System.Drawing.Point(p.X, p.Y);
        }

        public static implicit operator POINT(System.Drawing.Point p)
        {
            return new POINT(p.X, p.Y);
        }
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct RECT
    {
        public int Left;        // x position of upper-left corner
        public int Top;         // y position of upper-left corner
        public int Right;       // x position of lower-right corner
        public int Bottom;      // y position of lower-right corner
    }
}
```

---

Если целевое окно перекрывается другими окнами, соответствующая часть рамки будет скрыта. Чтобы рисовать рамку поверх всех окон, код рисования нужно изменить, используя контекст рабочего стола:

```
        //получаем окно в текущей позиции курсора  
        POINT pt;
        GetCursorPos(out pt);
        IntPtr hwnd = WindowFromPoint(pt);

        //получаем границы окна   
        RECT rc;
        GetWindowRect(hwnd, out rc);

        //формируем структуру для GDI+
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(rc.Left, rc.Top, rc.Right - rc.Left, rc.Bottom - rc.Top);

        //получаем контекст рабочего стола
        Graphics g = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromHwnd((IntPtr)0);
        using (g)
        {
            //рисуем прямоугольник
            g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, rect);
        }
```

Иллюстрация различия между этими двумя методами:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это уже что то, спасибо!
Но проблема до конца не решена(, возможно ли сделать так, что бы рамка рисовалась именно на том слое, где находится окно?

Comment: Что значит "именно на том слое, где находится окно"? Вы имеете в виду, если окно частично перекрыто другим окном, соответствующая часть рамки должна быть скрыта? Тогда я думаю, вместо рабочего стола надо рисовать в родительском окне целевого окна.

Comment: Чаще всего, родительское окно целевого элемента находится под другими элементами, и рамка, нарисованная на нем, перекрывается. Так же, пробовал рисовать на самих элементах, они часто, тоже, перекрываются. Даже и не знаю как быть. Но, в общем, Ваши советы очень мне помогли. Спасибо.

Comment: Немного не понял все таки, какое поведение при перекрытии вы ожидаете. На [картинке](http://vadim--111.narod.ru/files/drawing.png) слева показано перекрытие при рисовании на родительском окне, а справа - при рисовании на рабочем столе (текущий вариант). Вам нужно первое или второе (или вообще что-то третье)?

Comment: Мне нужно первое(то что слева), но реализовать это я смог от части...Например, окна Гугл Хрома не выделялись вообще, почти все системные окна выделялись, но, иногда, элементы окна перекрывали выделение других элементов этого же окна. Возможно я не совсем понял что значит "родительское окно"? Перепробовал `GetParent(IntPtr hWnd)`, `GetWindow(IntPtr hWnd, GetWindowType uCmd)` и `GetAncestor(IntPtr hwnd, GetAncestorFlags flags)`. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как его получить.

Comment: Обновил ответ. Да действительно, родительское окно это GetParent. Что касается Хрома и многих других приложений то да, не во всех случаях это будет работать. В приложениях, использующих Direct UI или WPF, отдельные элементы не являются окнами, для них этот метод не будет работать как вы ожидаете. Для приложений MFC, Borland C++/Delphi, Winforms обычно будет работать, но могут быть глюки, когда приложение затирает часть рамки через долю секунды, по неизвестной причине. В общем, "насильное" рисование в чужих контекстах не может быть идеальным.