# Как нарисовать рамку поверх окна приложения?

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi

Нужно нарисовать рамку, поверх окна приложения из списка запущенных приложений. То есть, пользователь выбирает приложение из списка запущенных, его окно становится активным и поверх его рисуется рамка. Я пробовал поулчить `hdc` этого приложения и нарисовать рамку на этом `hdc`, но выяснилось, что такой способ работать не будет.

В [аналогичной теме на английской версии сайта](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52858141/c-winapi-draw-border-on-top-of-application-window) мне предложили использовать Layered Windows, но, прочитав про технологию я не понял, как это можно использовать в моём случае. Хотелось бы пример.

Может кто сталкивался с подобным и может подсказать как можно решить мою проблему с использованием Layered Windows или без них?

Попробовал создать Layered окно, поместить его поверх нужного окна и нарисовать на layered окне рамку, но не вышло:

```
const COLORREF MY_COLOR_KEY = RGB(255, 128, 0);
HWND cmdHanlde = NULL;
constexpr unsigned int timerIdWindowUpdate = 1;
constexpr unsigned int timerIdFrameColor = 2;
bool tick = false;

int APIENTRY wWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
             _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
             _In_ LPWSTR    lpCmdLine,
             _In_ int       nCmdShow)
{
WNDCLASSEX wc = {};
wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
wc.lpszClassName = L"MyTransparentFrame";
wc.hCursor = ::LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
wc.hbrBackground = NULL;

wc.lpfnWndProc = [](HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp) -> LRESULT
{
switch (msg)
{
case WM_PAINT:
{
    PAINTSTRUCT ps{};
    HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);

    RECT rc{}; GetClientRect(hwnd, &rc);
    HPEN hPen = CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 5, tick ? RGB(255, 128, 1) : RGB(255, 201, 14));
    HBRUSH hBrush = CreateSolidBrush(MY_COLOR_KEY);
    HGDIOBJ hOldPen = SelectObject(hdc, hPen);
    HGDIOBJ hOldBrush = SelectObject(hdc, hBrush);

    Rectangle(hdc, rc.left, rc.top, rc.right, rc.bottom);

    if (hOldPen)
        SelectObject(hdc, hOldPen);
    if (hOldBrush)
    SelectObject(hdc, hOldBrush);
    if (hPen)
        DeleteObject(hPen);
    if (hBrush)
        DeleteObject(hBrush);

    EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
}
break;
case WM_TIMER:
{
    if (wp == timerIdWindowUpdate)
    {
        WINDOWPLACEMENT windowPlacement = { sizeof(WINDOWPLACEMENT), };
        if (::GetWindowPlacement(cmdHanlde, &windowPlacement))
        {
            if (windowPlacement.showCmd == SW_SHOWMINIMIZED
                || !IsWindowVisible(cmdHanlde))
            {
                ::SetWindowPos(hwnd, cmdHanlde, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_HIDEWINDOW);

            }
            else
            {
                RECT rect = {};
                ::GetWindowRect(cmdHanlde, &rect);
                MONITORINFO monInfo;
                monInfo.cbSize = sizeof(MONITORINFO);
                GetMonitorInfoW(MonitorFromWindow(cmdHanlde, MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST), &monInfo);
                if (cmdHanlde != NULL && ::IsZoomed(cmdHanlde))
                {
                    rect.left = monInfo.rcWork.left;
                    rect.top = monInfo.rcWork.top;
                    rect.bottom = monInfo.rcWork.bottom > rect.bottom ? rect.bottom : monInfo.rcWork.bottom;
                    rect.right = monInfo.rcWork.right > rect.right ? rect.right : monInfo.rcWork.right;
                }
                ::SetWindowPos(hwnd, 0, rect.left, rect.top, rect.right - rect.left, rect.bottom - rect.top,
                    SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
            }
        }
    }
    else if (wp == timerIdFrameColor)
    {
        tick = !tick;
        ::RedrawWindow(hwnd, NULL, NULL, RDW_INVALIDATE);
    }
    break;
}
case WM_DESTROY:
    PostQuitMessage(0);
    break;

default:
    return DefWindowProcW(hwnd, msg, wp, lp);
}

return 0;
};

RegisterClassEx(&wc);

HWND hwnd = CreateWindowExW(WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW | WS_EX_NOACTIVATE | WS_EX_LAYERED | WS_EX_TRANSPARENT, wc.lpszClassName, L"", WS_POPUP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_DISABLED,
0, 0, 0, 0, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);
::SetTimer(hwnd, timerIdWindowUpdate, 50, NULL);
::SetTimer(hwnd, timerIdFrameColor, 500, NULL);
SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hwnd, MY_COLOR_KEY, 255, LWA_COLORKEY);
ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_SHOW);
cmdHanlde = FindWindow(L"ConsoleWindowClass", L"C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\cmd.exe");

MSG msg;
while (GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0))
{
TranslateMessage(&msg);
DispatchMessage(&msg);
}

return (int)msg.wParam;
}
```

Comment: Создайте Layered окно, расположите его поверх целевого окна и рисуйте на нем.

Comment: @VTT, вы имеете в виду, сделать окно полностью прозрачным, получть DC этого окна и рисовать на этом DC?

Comment: Именно так.....

Comment: У вас полностью отсутствует проверка ошибок. Но главное, это отсутствие [цикла сообщений](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/LearnWin32/window-messages). `BeginPaint` можно вызывать только внутри обработчика `WM_PAINT`.

Comment: @VTT, проверку ошибок я убрал, чтобы сократить количество кода, т.к. в данном случае она малоинформативна. Цикл обработки сообщений был, но в нём отсутствовала обработка WM_PAINT. Я добавил, но лучше не стало.

Comment: Теперь у вас в обработчике `WM_PAINT` происходит проваливание в обработчик `WM_CLOSE`, который уничтожает окно. Цикл обработки сообщений совершенно необходим.

Comment: @VTT, добавил break в конце, но это ситуацию не поменяло. Цикл обработки - имеется в виду в main добавить GetMessage()?

Comment: Да, иначе ваше приложение сразу же выходит.

Answer (score 2):

Рисование в DC чужого окна определенно "работает". Другое дело, что:

- Нарисованное таким образом изображение затрется при первой обработке WM_PAINT в целевом окне (его понадобится постоянно перерисовывать).
- Если вам нужно рисовать рамку вокруг какого-то окна, вам нужен DC не этого окна, а его родительского окна (или рабочего стола, если это окно верхнего уровня). Ведь на DC окна можно рисовать только внутри этого окна, а рамка нужна снаружи.

Подробнее см. в похожем вопросе: [Рисование на окне другого приложения с помощью WinAPI](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/661585/%D0%A0%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-winapi/661636#661636)

---

Что касается layered window, вот так у меня работает:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK LayerWndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (msg)
    {
        case WM_PAINT:
        {
            HPEN framePen = ::CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 5, RGB(255, 0, 0));
            RECT rect = {};
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            ::GetClientRect(hwnd, &rect);
            HDC hdc = ::BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
            ::SelectObject(hdc, framePen);
            ::Rectangle(hdc, rect.left, rect.top, rect.right, rect.bottom);
            ::EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
        }
        break;
        case WM_CLOSE:
            DestroyWindow(hwnd);
            break;
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

void CreateLayer(){
    HWND handle = FindWindow(L"ConsoleWindowClass", L"C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\cmd.exe");

    SetForegroundWindow(handle);

    RECT rect = {};
    ::GetWindowRect(handle, &rect);

    WNDCLASSEX wx = {};
    wx.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wx.lpfnWndProc = LayerWndProc;
    wx.lpszClassName = L"TestBorderWindow";
    wx.hCursor = ::LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wx.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(LTGRAY_BRUSH);

    ::RegisterClassEx(&wx);

    HWND hWnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_LAYERED,
    L"TestBorderWindow",
    L"Demo",
    WS_POPUP,
    rect.left, rect.top,
    rect.right - rect.left, rect.bottom - rect.top,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    (HINSTANCE)GetModuleHandle(NULL),
    NULL);

    ::GetWindowRect(handle, &rect);
    SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hWnd, RGB(255,255,255), 0, LWA_COLORKEY);
    ::SetWindowPos(handle, hWnd, rect.left, rect.top, rect.right - rect.left, rect.bottom - rect.top,
    SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
    ShowWindow(hWnd,SW_SHOW);
}

int APIENTRY wWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
                     _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     _In_ LPWSTR    lpCmdLine,
                     _In_ int       nCmdShow)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hPrevInstance);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine);

    MSG msg;    

    CreateLayer();

    // Main message loop:
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {       
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);      
    }

    return (int) msg.wParam;
}
```

Comment: спасибо. Я обновил свой код (в первом сообщении). Теперь рамка рисуется и я сделал, что бы она моргала и изменялась в соответствии с размером окна (сделал с помощью таймеров). Если просто менять размер окна, то все ок. Но если его свернуть или развернуть, то рамка пропадает и больше не рисуется. Не подскажите, почему так?

Comment: @rudolfninja потому что ваш вызов `SetWindowPos(hwnd, cmdHanlde, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_HIDEWINDOW)` не только прячет окно, но и сбрасывает его размер в ноль. Замените его на `ShowWindow(hwnd,SW_HIDE);`, тогда он будет делать именно то, что вы ожидаете

Comment: @rudolfninja И в `SetWindowPos(hwnd, ... SWP_SHOWWINDOW)` вторым параметром нужно не ноль, а cmdHanlde. На попытку вывести левое неактивное окно поверх всех окон Windows дает отлуп, а вот расположить его под активным окном можно

Comment: @ MSDN.WhiteKnight, `ShowWindow(hwnd,SW_HIDE);` не помогло, все равно окна не видно при разворачивании. По поводу `SetWindowPos` если вторым параметром сделать cmdHandle, то рамка вообще не рисутеся.

Comment: @rudolfninja Вот рабочий вариант: https://pastebin.com/B0N7tWSU Нужно, чтобы layered window было чуть больше целевого окна, тогда можно отображать на нем рамку, будучи под целевым окном в Z-order. Иначе ничего не выйдет, так как Windows задает ограничения по выводу окон на самый верх в Z-order.

Comment: спасибо. Но в таком случае есть проблема, если развернуть окно, то не видно рамки. Я придумал как решить проблему. Возможно, вариант не самый красивый, но работает: https://pastebin.com/NdcqFXFw